# A problem with the way Submit button works in IE and Mozilla

Tags: forms, internet-explorer

I have a form in HTML in the following order

```
<form>
input field
<submit button1>
input field
<submit button2>
```

Now when I am pressend the "Enter" Hardkey from Keyboard, it is taking submit button2 in IE but not in Mozilla. For me Mozilla is working fine.

Can anyone help me out in this...

Comment: Why do you have one form with two submit buttons? Either have one submit button, or two separate forms.

Comment: Sir,
Its actually a full codebase and I am asked to solve a defect. Let me tell u my findings --- 
There is one javascript function --
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
   <!--
   function f1(){
   document.getElementById("form").f2.disabled = ((document.getElementById("form").f3.value == "Never"));
   }
   -->
   </SCRIPT>

on removin this code from the file, it works fine...But prob arises when I add this code. FYI. This part of the code was already added in the function

Answer (score 0):

You probably figured this out by now, but the disabled attribute is not a boolean value.  You need to set disabled to "disabled", but `(document.getElementById("form").f3.value == "Never")` evaluates to a boolean.